# Confusion with Java inheriting

Tags: java, inheritance

I am currently working through an AP CS Exam study guide and I have hit a brick wall in understanding whats going on. Lets say I have a class called Employee and I have another class that inherits Employee called Manager. Is there a difference between the following declarations?

```
Employee empl1 = new Manager();
Manager empl2 = new Manager();
```

Im basically confused on what the term before the name of the object is doing and how thats different than the term after new. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Static class and dynamic class, respectively. empl1 would inherit the dynamic methods from Manager and the static methods from Employee. empl2 would inherit the dynamic methods of Manager and the static methods of Manager.

Comment: Does your study guide actually say `new Manager;` without any parentheses?  The Java compiler will spit that out.  If it does, please let us know who the publisher is so we can send them a nasty letter :) :) :) :)

Comment: I apologize it should be Manager();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part before the name is the *type* of the reference to the object that you are creating. On the right side, after the `new`, you are calling a constructor, of one specific class (the class `Manager`, in your example).

You could write

```
Employee empl1 = new Manager();
Employee empl2 = new Consultant();
Employee empl3 = new Officer();
Employee empl4 = new Secretary();
```

because all of the objects that you are creating there are *Employees*. However, you could not write

```
Manager manager = new Secretary();
```

because a secretary is no manager.

The type of the reference (that is, the term before the name) determines which *methods* you may call using this reference. For example, you could write

```
Manager manager = new Manager();
manager.doSomethingThatOnlyManagersCanDo();
```

but you can *not* write

```
Employee employee = new Manager();
emplyoee.doSomethingThatOnlyManagersCanDo();
```

because you only know that the object is an employee, but not that is a manager. (It IS a manager, but you don't know it, because the reference only tells you that it is an employee)

Answer (score 0):

The form on the left is the "interface", inheritance allows you to use a `Manager` as an `Employee` because a `Manager` [is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Employee`. The difference is the methods that will be invoked on a Manager Employee come from `Manager` first, and then "inherit" behavior from `Employee`. Another difference would be if you called `getClass().getName()`. Consider that every Java Object inherits from [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), that is why you can call `toString()` or `equals()` on any Object.

Answer (score 0):

`empl1` and `empl2` will both be `Manager` objects.  The difference is in how the variables can be used in the rest of the method.

You've declared that `empl1` can be an `Employee`, or any object that is a subclass of `Employee` (including a `Manager`).  Any time you use `empl1` in the program, the compiler won't know that it's actually a `Manager`, only that it's some kind of `Employee`.  Thus, if `Manager` has any new methods that `Employee` doesn't have, you can't use them on `empl1`.  However, you can reassign `empl1` to be any other `Employee`, so that later on you could say something like

```
empl1 = new Employee(...some data...);
empl1 = new Intern(...some data...);
empl1 = new Accountant(...some data...);
```

or the like.  You can't do that with `empl2`, which is restricted to being only a `Manager` (or any subclasses of `Manager`, if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, both `empl1` and `empl2` are *variables* that you can assign objects to. The `empl1` variable can hold any kind of `Employee` object, but the `empl2` variable can only hold a `Manager` object. Since `Manager` is a kind of `Employee`, you can put a `Manager` object into an `Employee` variable. The `new` call tells Java to create a new object of the specified type.

The type in front of the variable name is called the *declared type*, and this type defines the interface (API) that the rest of your code is available to work with. For example, you can call the (hypothetical) `getEmployeeId()` method on `empl1` or `empl2`, but you can only call the `getManagerLevel()` method on `empl2`.

The type of the actual object that you put into the variable (`Manager` in both cases here) is called the *runtime type*, and it can be any type that extends or implements the declared type. The JVM takes care of routing method calls on the variable to the correct code for the runtime type.

Answer (score 0):

When you refer a base class with an object of type Super class, The object has access only to the overriding methods of the base class or in short only the the methods that the two classes have in common...
Referring to a base class object with a super class is what we call Virtual Method Invocation in java...